# How to find li tag and replace with another li tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the li with specific id and replace it with ll tag
Here is the code..

```
    var t = document.getElementById('idname').getAttribute('atrname');
     $('li.classname').each(function(element) {

       if(t == $(this).text()){
       $('.classname li').replaceWith('li');
     }
   });
```

html

```
<ul class="classname">
   <li id="idname" attrname"name"></li>
</ul>
```

thanks..

Comment: Also add your html

Comment: What do you mean by "ll", you want to replace as a class or as a element

Comment: @Vishnudev replace the element not the class(its li tag)

Comment: You wanna make a custom element named ll right?

Comment: @Vishnudev no want replace <li></li> tag with another <li></li> tag

Comment: What are you trying to get with that replacement? What exactly is the problem because maybe we can help you solve it...

Comment: @A.Meshu Find the element with id , if the value of id matches with li tag then replace it with another li tag ..

Comment: @Sachin Does the answer below meets your requirements?

Comment: @TusharShukla No it does not replaces the li tag but thanks for the answer

Comment: Well then I'd suggest you either add some more code (html, js) or lemme know if there is any error so as to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this should answer your question:

```
var t = document.getElementById('idname').getAttribute('atrname');
$('li.classname').each(function(element) {
  if(t == $(this).text()){
      // New LI element with same id as original LI
      let newLi = "<li id='someId'>This is new li replacing prev LI with #someId</li>";
      // Appending new LI next to original LI and then removing original LI
      $('#someId').after(newLi).remove();
  }
});
```

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharshuklaa/hL65w9sm/2/) as well.
Let me know if this helps!